# Does Django 1.11 still support function base view for auth module?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

It has been written in release notes of Django 1.11 that auth module will now support class base view and not function base view.
Since we're migrating from 1.10 to 1.11 we can see that our **older function base view is still working with django 1.11**.

we've referred below link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/

Whether the behavior are expected or not ?
Do we need to rewrite class base view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/).

According to it, the function-based auth views [will be removed in 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-1):

> *2.1:*
>
> contrib.auth.views.login(), logout(), password_change(), password_change_done(), password_reset(), password_reset_done(), password_reset_confirm(), and password_reset_complete() will be removed.

Comment: Then why they've mentioned on release notes of 1.11 that contrib.auth’s login() and logout() function-based views are deprecated in favor of new class-based views LoginView and LogoutView.

Comment: Because they are _marked deprecated_ in that version, but not removed yet, so people can start migrating away from them.

Comment: It's worth knowing you can run Python with the flag `-Wd`, e.g. `python -Wd manage.py runserver` (or while running tests), so you can see all the deprecation warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that the behavior is as intended -- when something is
"deprecated", it doesn't get removed immediately; see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/deprecation/ which
includes both a link to the general deprecation policy, and a
specification of the deprecation timeline for the specific
functionality you asked about.

Conclusion: However they've mentioned in backward incompatible change, **this will get deprecated gradually**.

I've received above message from django community.
Hopefully this will be helpful.